# Check for duplicates, PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, duplicates

I have the following code, which works perfectly. I want the user to get an error message if the e-mail address that he typed already exists in the database!
Thank you!

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("xxxx.com","xxxx_xxx","xxxx","yyyyy_");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['postcode']);
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['country']);
$phonenumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phonenumber']);
$rating = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rating']);

$sql="INSERT INTO customers (firstname, lastname, password, email, address, postcode,   country, phonenumber, rating)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$password', '$email', '$address', '$postcode', '$country', '$phonenumber', '$rating')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Did you not Google this before asking? Use `mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: *snicker* you're being ridiculous @Fred-ii- Google is too hard.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Isn't that a chocolate bar? Now you've done it, I now have the munchies. *Snickers*

Comment: I ordered a drink at a chocolate bar once... @Fred-ii-

Comment: @JayBlanchard Check out the salad bar at Fred's `foo` bar while you're in town ;)

Comment: @MixalisPapoulakis: \*cough* UNIQUE \*cough*.

Comment: Sounds like you need a drink from the chocolate bar @lxg

Answer (score 3):

Here, use a [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) method and [`num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}

$check_email = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email=?");
    $check_email->bind_param("s", $email);
    $check_email->execute();
    $check_email->store_result(); 
    $row_check = $check_email->num_rows;

if($row_check  > 0 ) {

// your error message or make it die.

$check_email->close(); 
$con->close();

}
```

---

Another way to make sure that no duplicate records exists in DB, is to make your column(s) as [`UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

---

or:

```
$check_email = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM customers where email= '".$email."' ");

$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($check_email);

if($numrows > 0){
    die("Email exists already.");
}

else {

    echo "Does NOT exist."; // continue and insert into DB

}
```

Using a prepared statements method is better and safer.

Answer (score 0):

Use **select** statement to retrieve rows with input e-mail and check whether row count > 0.

Comment: If the OP has the e-mail column set to unique an error will be thrown. No need for a separate query.